# UITableView beginUpdates endUpdates scrolls to the top of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

This is what I am doing so as to set the focus on the same point after `UITableView` `beginUpdates` :

```
CGPoint offset = tableMessageDetail.contentOffset;
// CGPoint textPoint = [self.view convertPoint:cell.txtReply.frame.origin toView:nil];
[tableMessageDetail beginUpdates];
[tableMessageDetail endUpdates];
[tableMessageDetail setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
//[tableMessageDetail scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

But the position after `endUpdates`, when the cell is too high, comes to the top of cell. I have tried with the commented approach as well, but that too is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a thought, hope this helps:
Remove all animations on the tableView's layer before setting the contentOffset.

```
[tableView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
```

and then,

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:cell.indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```